# How to fix Prisma Client getting undefined for custom model

Tags: javascript, typescript, rest, express, prisma

I generated a project from [typescript-express-starter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-express-starter) and selected [Prisma](https://www.prisma.io/) as the ORM.
The basic 'User' model generated by the starter project is working fine. I created a model 'Product' as the existing 'User' model. I added it in [schema.prisma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMFsH.png) and created a products.services.ts.

```js
import { PrismaClient, Product } from '@prisma/client';
import { CreateProductDto } from '@dtos/products.dto';
import HttpException from '@exceptions/HttpException';
import { isEmpty } from '@utils/util';

class ProductService {
  public products = new PrismaClient().product;

  public async findAllProducts(): Promise<Product[]> {
    const allProducts: Product[] = await this.products.findMany();
    return allProducts;
  }

  
}

export default ProductService;
```

The problem is while the **PrismaClient().user** is returning a prisma model but **PrismaClient().product** is returning undefined. The generated PrismaClient typescript files have the products model and associated methods and it is also showing in the VS Code hints. However when running the project PrismaClient().products is returning undefined instead of the actual model. When running the prisma studio, it is showing the models.

[Products Model - Failed API Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6wth.png)

[Users Model - Successful API Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoMaY.png)

[Prisma Models in Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnqyu.png)

[User Model in Prisma Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NC7X6.png)

[Products Model in Prisma Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwImx.png)

I could not find any solution from the available documentation or forums. My most probable guess is that I am missing some configuration or files that need to be added to work. But I don't know where and what that could be. Please help out.

This is the log of **new PrismaClient()**.

```html
server        | PrismaClient:  <ref *1> NewPrismaClient [PrismaClient] {
server        |   _middlewares: [],
server        |   _engineMiddlewares: [],
server        |   _transactionId: 1,
server        |   _rejectOnNotFound: undefined,
server        |   _clientVersion: '2.23.0',
server        |   _activeProvider: 'mysql',
server        |   _errorFormat: 'colorless',
server        |   _dmmf: DMMFClass {
server        |     outputTypeToMergedOutputType: [Function (anonymous)],
server        |     datamodel: { enums: [], models: [Array] },
server        |     schema: {
server        |       inputObjectTypes: [Object],
server        |       outputObjectTypes: [Object],
server        |       enumTypes: [Object]
server        |     },
server        |     mappings: { modelOperations: [Array], otherOperations: [Object] },
server        |     enumMap: { UserScalarFieldEnum: [Object], SortOrder: [Object] },
server        |     datamodelEnumMap: {},
server        |     queryType: {
server        |       name: 'Query',
server        |       fields: [Array],
server        |       isEmbedded: false,
server        |       fieldMap: [Object]
server        |     },
server        |     mutationType: {
server        |       name: 'Mutation',
server        |       fields: [Array],
server        |       isEmbedded: false,
server        |       fieldMap: [Object]
server        |     },
server        |     modelMap: { User: [Object] },
server        |     outputTypes: { model: [Array], prisma: [Array] },
server        |     outputTypeMap: {
server        |       User: [Object],
server        |       Query: [Object],
server        |       Mutation: [Object],
server        |       AggregateUser: [Object],
server        |       UserGroupByOutputType: [Object],
server        |       AffectedRowsOutput: [Object],
server        |       UserCountAggregateOutputType: [Object],
server        |       UserAvgAggregateOutputType: [Object],
server        |       UserSumAggregateOutputType: [Object],
server        |       UserMinAggregateOutputType: [Object],
server        |       UserMaxAggregateOutputType: [Object]
server        |     },
server        |     inputObjectTypes: { prisma: [Array] },
server        |     inputTypeMap: {
server        |       UserWhereInput: [Object],
server        |       UserOrderByInput: [Object],
server        |       UserWhereUniqueInput: [Object],
server        |       UserScalarWhereWithAggregatesInput: [Object],
server        |       UserCreateInput: [Object],
server        |       UserUncheckedCreateInput: [Object],
server        |       UserUpdateInput: [Object],
server        |       UserUncheckedUpdateInput: [Object],
server        |       UserCreateManyInput: [Object],
server        |       UserUpdateManyMutationInput: [Object],
server        |       UserUncheckedUpdateManyInput: [Object],
server        |       IntFilter: [Object],
server        |       StringFilter: [Object],
server        |       IntWithAggregatesFilter: [Object],
server        |       StringWithAggregatesFilter: [Object],
server        |       StringFieldUpdateOperationsInput: [Object],
server        |       IntFieldUpdateOperationsInput: [Object],
server        |       NestedIntFilter: [Object],
server        |       NestedStringFilter: [Object],
server        |       NestedIntWithAggregatesFilter: [Object],
server        |       NestedFloatFilter: [Object],
server        |       NestedStringWithAggregatesFilter: [Object]
server        |     },
server        |     mappingsMap: { User: [Object] },
server        |     rootFieldMap: {
server        |       findFirstUser: [Object],
server        |       findManyUser: [Object],
server        |       aggregateUser: [Object],
server        |       groupByUser: [Object],
server        |       findUniqueUser: [Object],
server        |       createOneUser: [Object],
server        |       upsertOneUser: [Object],
server        |       createManyUser: [Object],
server        |       deleteOneUser: [Object],
server        |       updateOneUser: [Object],
server        |       updateManyUser: [Object],
server        |       deleteManyUser: [Object],
server        |       executeRaw: [Object],
server        |       queryRaw: [Object]
server        |     }
server        |   },
server        |   _previewFeatures: [],
server        |   _engineConfig: {
server        |     cwd: '/app/src/prisma',
server        |     dirname: '/app/node_modules/.prisma/client',
server        |     enableDebugLogs: false,
server        |     enableEngineDebugMode: undefined,
server        |     datamodelPath: '/app/node_modules/.prisma/client/schema.prisma',
server        |     prismaPath: undefined,
server        |     engineEndpoint: undefined,
server        |     datasources: [],
server        |     generator: {
server        |       name: 'client',
server        |       provider: [Object],
server        |       output: [Object],
server        |       config: {},
server        |       binaryTargets: [],
server        |       previewFeatures: []
server        |     },
server        |     showColors: false,
server        |     logLevel: undefined,
server        |     logQueries: undefined,
server        |     env: {
server        |       PORT: '3000',
server        |       DATABASE_URL: 'mysql://root:password@mysql:3306/prisma'
server        |     },
server        |     flags: [],
server        |     clientVersion: '2.23.0',
server        |     previewFeatures: [],
server        |     useUds: undefined,
server        |     activeProvider: 'mysql'
server        |   },
server        |   _engine: NodeEngine {
server        |     startCount: 0,
server        |     previewFeatures: [],
server        |     useUds: false,
server        |     stderrLogs: '',
server        |     handleRequestError: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
server        |     dirname: '/app/node_modules/.prisma/client',
server        |     env: {
server        |       PORT: '3000',
server        |       DATABASE_URL: 'mysql://root:password@mysql:3306/prisma'
server        |     },
server        |     cwd: '/app/src/prisma',
server        |     enableDebugLogs: false,
server        |     enableEngineDebugMode: false,
server        |     datamodelPath: '/app/node_modules/.prisma/client/schema.prisma',
server        |     prismaPath: undefined,
server        |     generator: {
server        |       name: 'client',
server        |       provider: [Object],
server        |       output: [Object],
server        |       config: {},
server        |       binaryTargets: [],
server        |       previewFeatures: []
server        |     },
server        |     datasources: [],
server        |     logEmitter: EventEmitter {
server        |       _events: [Object: null prototype],
server        |       _eventsCount: 1,
server        |       _maxListeners: undefined,
server        |       [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
server        |     },
server        |     showColors: false,
server        |     logLevel: undefined,
server        |     logQueries: false,
server        |     clientVersion: '2.23.0',
server        |     flags: [],
server        |     activeProvider: 'mysql',
server        |     engineEndpoint: undefined,
server        |     platformPromise: Promise { <pending> },
server        |     getConfigPromise: Promise { <pending> }
server        |   },
server        |   _fetcher: PrismaClientFetcher {
server        |     prisma: [Circular *1],
server        |     debug: false,
server        |     hooks: undefined,
server        |     dataloader: Dataloader { options: [Object], tickActive: false, batches: {} }
server        |   },
server        |   user: {
server        |     findUnique: [Function (anonymous)],
server        |     findFirst: [Function (anonymous)],
server        |     findMany: [Function (anonymous)],
server        |     create: [Function (anonymous)],
server        |     createMany: [Function (anonymous)],
server        |     delete: [Function (anonymous)],
server        |     update: [Function (anonymous)],
server        |     deleteMany: [Function (anonymous)],
server        |     updateMany: [Function (anonymous)],
server        |     upsert: [Function (anonymous)],
server        |     count: [Function (anonymous)],
server        |     aggregate: [Function (anonymous)],
server        |     groupBy: [Function (anonymous)]
server        |   }
server        | }
```

Comment: Here, In the log of prismaclient there is only user model there and not the others such as products and offers.

Comment: **UPDATE** the prisma query is working but the prisma client is not providing the basic model defined in schema

Answer (score 11):

I had this same problem too today, until I learned that after every change to the `schema.prisma` file, I need to run:

```
npx prisma generate
```

And then also generate the migration with

```
npx prisma migrate dev --name name_of_stuff
```

But it was the first one that fixed the exact error you stated above.

Comment: Not sure now new users are supposed to know this... There really needs to be a comment somewhere noticable/seeable in the schema within Prisma's templates to let users know this is necesarry.

Comment: Also, here's a link to the docs about the migrate command: https://www.prisma.io/docs/getting-started/setup-prisma/start-from-scratch/relational-databases/using-prisma-migrate-typescript-postgres

Comment: In my case I also had to restart the editor. I use Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 5):

I faced the similar issue earlier. To resolve that, I added a custom path for generating the prisma client inside the schema.prisma file as below -

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
  output   = "./src/generated/client"
}
```

and then imported the prisma client from the output path as below -

```
const { PrismaClient } = require('./src/generated/client')
const prisma = new PrismaClient()
```

This ensures you are not referring any wrong path while importing the prisma client.

Comment: This fixed my issue of no intellisense showing up. npx prisma generate didn't help me regardless of using .js or .ts.. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

It should just be:

```
public products = new PrismaClient();
```

Then you can use `this.products.findMany()`.

Note: Although this is not the correct approach. Using a single instance of PrismaClient across the entire project is [recommended](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/working-with-prismaclient/instantiate-prisma-client#the-number-of-prismaclient-instances-matters).

Comment: This is not working. I've even tried to create PrismaClient instance in a seperate file and importing it in other files. Still the prebuilt user model is working but my custom models are not.

Comment: What do you mean by custom model? Prisma only allows you to use the models defined in your `schema.prisma` file that maps to your database tables.

Comment: Models are already defined in schema.prisma. Upon migration, it is generating the models and their types too. It looks all good in development while writing code. but when I am running the project. Then the operations are failing. Any method of those models is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it turned out to be that I had accidentally commented out the `@Injectable()` decorator in my service class, which resulted in `this.prisma` being undefined.