# Prisma client returns undefined

Tags: orm, prisma

I'm new to using the Prisma client (With NodeJS & Postgres) and have hit an issue similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67774292/how-to-fix-prisma-client-getting-undefined-for-custom-model), but the answer doesn't fix the issue for me.

I'm seeing that the Prisma client correctly generates the SQL for my queries, **but always seems to return undefined**.

Example:

```js
const result = await this.databaseService.venue.findFirst({
      where: venueWhereUniqueInput,
      include: {
        bookingProvider: true,
      },
    });
```

Since the SQL is correct and I have manually run the SQL to check records are returned, I can only assume there's an issue with Prisma mapping the results to my model.

I have tried the following:

1. Checked if there's any outstanding migrations:

`npx prisma migrate dev --name name_of_stuff`

`npx prisma migrate dev`

2. Generated the Primsa models (Typescript generated models look correct)

`npx prisma generate`

3. Turned on verbose logging to check for any errors

`export DEBUG="*"`

But alas, I keep getting undefined results, please can someone advise how this can be resolved, many thanks!

Prisma version:  "prisma": "^3.5.0",